# How to Ignore Swipe gesture To use touchBegan

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swipe

When i run this program every time I touch the screen I would like the ball to move down. The problem is that every time I do that, the Swipe gesture(Moving Right) recognize the touch as well when I don't want it too. Which will cause the ball to move Sideway(Applied the touch and swipe).

Is there a way to ignore the Swipe gesture so my touchBegan is alone.

ViewController.h

```
int MoveBallRight;
int MoveBallDown;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *Ball;

    __weak IBOutlet UIButton *StartButton;

}
- (IBAction)StartButton:(id)sender;


@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)StartButton:(id)sender {
    MoveBallRight = 30;
    MoveBallDown = 30;


    StartButton.hidden = YES;


    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight)]; swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight; [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];



}
-(void)handleSwipeRight{

    Ball.center = CGPointMake(Ball.center.x + MoveBallRight, Ball.center.y);

}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    Ball.center = CGPointMake(Ball.center.x , Ball.center.y + MoveBallDown);

}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

THis might help

```
swipeRight.cancelsTouchesInView = YES
```

Comment: Sorry I'm still a noob at this. Would i put this under the -(void)handleSwipRight; ?

Comment: UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight)]; swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight; swipeRight.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

Comment: Its still going sideway after removing my old code with that T.T

Answer (score 0):

i think if you only want to move your object downward, then instead of using `Ball.center.x` in your `touchesBegan` method use constant value for x

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    Ball.center = CGPointMake(<Use Constant here> , Ball.center.y + MoveBallDown);
}
```

and use

```
swipeLeft.cancelsTouchesInView=YES;
swipeRight.cancelsTouchesInView=YES;
```

Comment: Sorry still new. What do you mean constant value of x. Where do i get that to put in the <>

Comment: Btw the ball already moves downward by it self. I just need the right swipe gesture alone.